# How to position floating hints in an Android TextInputEditText view

Tags: android, material-design

Using `TextInputEditText` inside a `TextInputLayout` in an Android layout xaml, it's possible to create Matrial style text input fields with 'fly up' hint text which moves out of the way as you start typing. How can the hint be made to appear further above the inputted text than it does by default?

Edit: You asked for pictures...

[image]

Comment: Please provide screenshots - actual and expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this rather simply by putting a top padding on the `TextInputEditText`. For example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

---

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Well I never. I thought I'd tried that! I don't suppose you know how to increase the space between the hint and the line *before* your start typing?

Comment: Right? I was trying all sorts of other things, like a spacer `View`, oversizing the `TextInputLayout`, etc., before I thought of that. Who'd've thought it'd be so simple? Anyhoo, lemme think about that one. I'm afraid that might be a little more involved, since `TextInputLayout` commandeers the `EditText`'s hint, and uses a private helper class to draw it. I'll let ya know if I come up with something simple. If not, do you wanna mess with a custom subclass? I know it can be done like that, but it takes some reflection, too.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid subclassing it. If there's no official way of doing it I'm happy to leave it. It's just often so difficult to find if there's a simple solution you're missing, orginal question case in point. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, I'd figured out a really simple subclass without reflection, but if you don't wanna deal with that, I don't really blame ya, for such a small effect. However, I just thought of and tested another possibility, but it would have to be done in code; no simple layout trick with this one. You can fiddle with the `EditText`'s bottom padding when its focus changes. If it does _not_ have focus _and_ its text is empty, then set that padding to, e.g., +15dp; else, set that padding to normal. I've got a snippet, if you'd like, but it's Java. I'm not sure what you're using.